# Stream was not writable

Tags: c#, .net, streamwriter

I am trying to read response from the web SOAP Api and getting `Stream was not writable` error on the second run in the foreach loop. With the first value in the `list ArrayList`  it works as expected but with the second value it says that `Stream was not writable` on the `Stream was not writable` line. What am I doing wrong?

```
        WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://www.api.com/v2.0/xml/");
        HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)webRequest;
        httpRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
        httpRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
        httpRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        Stream requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream();

        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream, Encoding.ASCII);

        StringBuilder soapRequest;

        foreach (var bol in list) { 
        oRequest =  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
        oRequest = oRequest + "<file>";
        oRequest = oRequest + "<IntDocNumber>" + bol + "</IntDocNumber>";
        oRequest = oRequest + "</file>";

        soapRequest  = new StringBuilder(oRequest);
         streamWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream, Encoding.ASCII);
        streamWriter.Write(soapRequest.ToString());
        streamWriter.Close();

        //Get the Response    
        HttpWebResponse wr = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader srd = new StreamReader(wr.GetResponseStream());
        string resulXmlFromWebService = srd.ReadToEnd();

        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(resulXmlFromWebService);

        XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/root/data/item");
        }
```

Comment: I'd try to declare the StreamWriter inside of the foreach loop if it is possible for your solution

Comment: I did that. The result is the same

Comment: You can't reuse the same request object for multiple requests. You simply have to create a new one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All HTTP communication happens as three steps:

- client opens a connection
- client sends its headers and data (in your case, the XML document) and ends the input (in your case where you close the request stream)
- server sends its response and closes the connection

So, when you close the connection, you cannot send anything else, because you have to wait for the server answer. If you want to send more data, move the beginning of your code (where you create a new WebRequest) inside the For loop.